# Value Subtraction Script for PHP Variable

Tags: javascript, php

I would like a Value Subtraction Script, For Discount in REAL.

Example: the Customer makes a Purchase of **$140.00** (Registered in the DB), on the Checkout Page, I want to print a Discount of **$10.00**

So that the value of **$130.00** appeared to him, how could I do that with a simple script in PHP

```
<?=number_format($order[0]->total_order_value, 2, ',', '.'); ?>
```

//$140,00 to **130,00**

How to do this magic with simple script inside this variable?

Comment: What's the problem? Just subtract it: `$order[0]->total_order_value - $discount`

Comment: @Barmar Thanks! Yes I wish that way, but how do I do it inside the code to give the $"10" discount?

Comment: Just put it as the first argument to `number_format()`. Do you think there's something different about function arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do the subtraction in the argument to `number_format()`

```
<?php $discount = 10; echo number_format($order[0]->total_order_value - $discount, 2, ',', '.'); ?>
```